# Any idea why Doxygen finds version.h.in but does not parse it as C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, documentation, doxygen

I have many projects with a `version.h.in` file which CMake converts to dynamically add the current version of the project.

Here is an example of `version.h.in`:

```
#define    LPP_VERSION_MAJOR   @LPP_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define    LPP_VERSION_MINOR   @LPP_VERSION_MINOR@
#define    LPP_VERSION_PATCH   @LPP_VERSION_PATCH@
#define    LPP_VERSION_BUILD   @LPP_VERSION_BUILD@
#if LPP_VERSION_PATCH
#define    LPP_VERSION_STRING  "@LPP_VERSION_MAJOR@.@LPP_VERSION_MINOR@.@LPP_VERSION_PATCH@"
#else
#define    LPP_VERSION_STRING  "@LPP_VERSION_MAJOR@.@LPP_VERSION_MINOR@"
#endif

int             get_major_version();
int             get_release_version();
int             get_patch_version();
char const *    get_version_string();
```

Somehow, Doxygen 1.8.13 doesn't pick up anything in this file. It looks like it gets ignored.

I use the `EXTENSION_MAPPING` and `FILE_PATTERNS` but it does not seem to help:

```
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = h.in=C++ \
                         hpp.in=C++

FILE_PATTERNS          = *.h \
                         *.h.in \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.hpp.in \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c
```

Could I be missing something?

Note that the `version.h.in` file appears in Doxygen's output. So the `FILE_PATTERNS` works as expected. However, it detects nothing within the file. For example, I have a `\file` entry like so:

```
/** \file
 * \brief This library version information.
 *
 * ...snip...
 */
```

The brief and full file descriptions are ignored.

IMPORTANT NOTE: I'm trying to get the `version.h.in` file. I know I could instead tell Doxygen about the `version.h` but then the version would change in the documentation which is not what I want.

### Update

As mentioned by @anarthal in a comment, the problem seems to be that the `EXTENSION_MAPPING` requires a single extension. Not a double extension.

I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7049) on github.

For my project I can actually use `.in` (that is `in=C++`) since I only have C++, but I hope this will get fixed at some point.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but you use `version.in.h` and `version.h.in` interchangeably. Is this intended?

Comment: @schaiba, sorry, my mistake here. It's correct in my code. Always `version.h.in` as expected.

Comment: May it be because the file has double extension? I have reproduced your problem when using a .h.in. However, if I change it to a custom single extension (version.mycustom), change EXTENSION_MAPPINGS and FILE_PATTERNS accordingly, it works fine.

Comment: @anarthal you mean setting `EXTENSION_MAPPINGS` to e.g. `.in`? Which version of doxygen did you use?

Comment: @albert I updated my answer. I used 1.8.11 and 1.8.13. It actually works if I use `in=C++`. But that means I'm limited to one language for `.in` files...

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely a workaround. I used the one which comes with Ubuntu 18 (so 1.8.13).